# Processing and splitting lines within batch files

Tags: batch-file

I have to process a text file which contains a bunch of events that look like

```
event_name1 : dd.mm.yyyy
event_name2 : dd.mm.yyyy
...
enemt_nameN : dd.mm.yyyy
```

I don't know how many lines there are before hands

then I have to extract a date from each line and parse it to find a date I am looking for.
if the date is the one needed, I need to echo the event name and keep searching

I can parse the file line by line but then a line won't split. Everywhere I am using the same command as you might see below

```
    @echo off

    rem parsing today's date and saving variables i will need later
    echo %date%
    for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=-" %%a in ("%date%") do (
    set day = %%a
    set month = %%b
    set year = %%c
    )

    rem parsing the file with events
    FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i IN (Dates.txt) DO (

    rem trying to work with the current line
    for /f "tokens=1-3 delims= " %%j in (%%i) do (
    set /f name = %%a
    set /f inputdate = %%c

    rem doing stuff with the date in the line, i need to parse it by day, month and year
    for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=." %%k in (%inputdate%) do (
    if /I "%day%" EQU %%a echo %inputdate%
    )
    )
    )
```

I expect the line to be split normally, however, I keep getting an error like "unable to find the file event_name" at each loop where I try to parse a string

Echo output in the cmd looks like this, for example:

```
    (for /F "tokens=1-3 delims= " %j in (tomorrow : 12.06.2019) do (
    set /f name = %a
    set /f inputdate = %c
    for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=." %k in ((null)) do (if /I "" EQU %a echo  
    )
    ) )
    Unable to find the file tomorrow.
```

Comment: check your `for` variables. When you do `for /f "tokens=1,-3" %%i ...`, you should use `%%i` and `%%k` instead of `%%a` and `%%c`. You have a few of those quirks in your code.

Comment: There is no `set /F`! And remove _spaces_ around the equal-to sign: `set VAR=Value`, or even better, `set "VAR=Value"`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when I understand correctly what you try to do, the following one-liner should be enough:

```
for /f "delims=:" %%a in ('type Dates.txt^|find "%date%"') do @echo %%a
```

Comment: A simpler `for /f "delims=:" %%a in ('find "%date%" Dates.txt') do @echo %%a` do the same and is slightly faster...

Comment: @Aacini: you are right, but `find "%date%" Dates.txt` returns a "header" of `---------- Dates.txt`, which I try to avoid. `find "%date%" <Dates.txt` should be about the same speed as `find "%date%" Dates.txt` and also avoids the header line.