# How to print part of the line in a text file using batch file commands

Tags: windows, batch-file

```
-rwx------ root;SQL_ root;Doma      393216 Jul 05 05:00 V:\MSSQL\Backup\mydb\mydb_backup_2020_07_05_050000_9821955.trn
-rwx------ root;SQL_ root;Doma      393216 Jul 05 06:00 V:\MSSQL\Backup\mydb\mydb_backup_2020_07_05_060001_9241754.trn
-rwx------ root;SQL_ root;Doma      393216 Jul 05 07:00 V:\MSSQL\Backup\mydb\mydb_backup_2020_07_05_070001_7545780.trn
-rwx------ root;SQL_ root;Doma      393216 Jul 05 08:00 V:\MSSQL\Backup\mydb\mydb_backup_2020_07_05_080001_4850750.trn
-rwx------ root;SQL_ root;Doma      393216 Jul 05 09:00 V:\MSSQL\Backup\mydb\mydb_backup_2020_07_05_090001_3588313.trn
-rwx------ root;SQL_ root;Doma      393216 Jul 05 10:00 V:\MSSQL\Backup\mydb\mydb_backup_2020_07_05_100001_2038178.trn
-rwx------ root;SQL_ root;Doma      393216 Jul 05 11:00 V:\MSSQL\Backup\mydb\mydb_backup_2020_07_05_110000_9809957.trn
```

these details are in a text file and I want only the file names like `V:\MSSQL\Backup\mydb\mydb_backup_2020_07_05_050000_9821955.trn` and pass it to delete command.

I used this command in a batch file

```
FOR /F %%i IN (<file location>) DO del /Q %%i.
```

However it fails as it reads the 1st line and has special characters `-rwx-----`.

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56550041/62576) help?

Comment: read the output of `for /?`, especially the part about `tokens` and `delims`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, this command helped me:

```
FOR /F "tokens=8 delims= " %a IN (<file_name> or <file_path>) do del %a
```

Ex: as a command:

```
FOR /F "tokens=8 delims= " %a IN (N:\Test_Folder\DELETE-FILES-20200709_195526) do del %a
```

in a batch file:

```
FOR /F "tokens=8 delims= " %%a IN (N:\Test_Folder\DELETE-FILES-20200709_195526) do del %%a
```

Comment: To protect you from potential space characters in the filename path, it would be prudent to use `Tokens=7,*`; then the filename would be assigned to `%%b`.